# Placing symbol over relation without changing where superscripts are placed

Tags: math-mode, mathtools, overset

I would like to place a symbol over a relation without changing where superscript are placed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand{\rel}{\rhd}
\newcommand{\symb}{\text{I}}

\newcommand{\testmyrel}[1]{%
  \begin{center}%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth/2}%
    \noindent Text text text\\%
    $\text{T} #1^* \text{U}$\\%
    $\text{T} \rel^* \text{U}$\\%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{center}%
}%

\begin{document}
    
My goal is to place a symbol (e.g. $\symb$) over a rel (e.g. $\rel$) that can be used in text without overlapping with text above, and handles superscripts as if it did not have a symbol:
\begin{center}%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth/2}%
        \noindent Text text text\\%
        $\text{T} \mathrel{\overset{\symb}{\rel}\vphantom{\rel}^*} \text{U}$\\%
        $\text{T} \rel^* \text{U}$\\%
    \end{minipage}%
\end{center}%

However, I do not want the superscript to be an argument of the command, which rules out the code above.

\begin{itemize}

\item Using overset makes the star too high:%
    \testmyrel{%
        \mathrel{%
            \overset{%
                \symb%
            }{%
                \mathord{\rel}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
%
\item Smashing the rel makes it go over the text:%
    \testmyrel{%
        \mathrel{%
            \smash{
                \overset{\symb}{\mathord{\rel}}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
%
\item Smashing the symbol makes it go over the text:%
\testmyrel{%
    \mathrel{%
        \overset{%
            \smash{\symb}%
        }{%
            \mathord{\rel}%
        }%
    }%
}%
%
\item Adding a vphantom inside mathrel leads to the star being too high:%
    \testmyrel{%
        \mathrel{%
            \overset{\symb}{\mathord{\rel}}%
            \vphantom{\symb}%
        }%
    }%
%
\item Adding a vphantom after mathrel leads to the star being misplaced to the right:%
\testmyrel{%
    \mathrel{%
        \overset{\symb}{\mathord{\rel}}%
    }%
    \vphantom{\symb}%
}%

\item Accentset without mathrel does not have the spacing due to mathrel:
\testmyrel{%
    \accentset{\symb}{\mathord{\rel}}%
}%

\item Accentset with mathrel puts the star too high:
\testmyrel{%
    \mathrel{\accentset{\symb}{\mathord{\rel}}}%
}%
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated, remember that `\text` is not for writing something upright. That is not what that command does. Use `\mathrm `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\text` for typesetting things in upright type in math, it doesn't generally work; use `\mathrm`.

Also `\rhd` is *not* a relation symbol, but it's not difficult to make it such.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,accents}

% \rhd is not a relation symbol
\mathchardef\rel=\numexpr\rhd+"1000

\newcommand{\overrel}[2]{%
  \mathrel{\accentset{#1}{#2}}%
  \mathrel{\vphantom{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Text text text\\
$T \overrel{\mathrm{I}}{\rel}^* U$\\
$T \rel^* U$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, with `\overset`:

```
\newcommand{\overrel}[2]{%
  \overset{#1}{#2}%
  \mathrel{\vphantom{#2}}%
}
```

[image]

The trick is that TeX adds no space, and no line break point either, between consecutive relation atoms. So we can add the subscripts/superscripts to a phantom relation.