# Ignoring overset width for subscript placement

Tags: subscripts, overset

I have a relation symbol that has parameters both above it and as subscripts. I would like the placement of each kind of parameters to be independent of the other parameter, and in particular:

- when the overset becomes larger than the relation symbol, the subscript should not be moved to the right; and
- the length of the subscript should have no impact on the horizontal placement of the overset.

Here are my attempts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix2}

\stackMath
\newcommand{\mystackon}[2]{\ThisStyle{\stackon[0.1ex]{\SavedStyle#1}{\SavedStyle#2}}}%

\newcommand{\oversetred}[2]{\mathrel{\vphantom{#1}}\mathrel{\mystackon{\mathord{#1}}{#2}}\mathrel{\vphantom{#1}}}% This ensures that the height of superscripts is unaffected by the overset. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643265/placing-symbol-over-relation-without-changing-where-superscripts-are-placed

% One of my use cases. Exact values are unimportant, only that \myover is wider than \mysymb, and that the solution should allow for other values
\newcommand{\mysymb}{\sqsubseteq}
\newcommand{\myover}{{\scriptscriptstyle \mathbfscr{K},\mathbfscr{P}}}
\newcommand{\mysub}{\rightsquigarrow}

\begin{document}
Attempts:\\\\
$A\oversetred{\mysymb}{\myover}_\mysub B$ : the $\mysub$ is too far from the $\mysymb$\\\\
$A\oversetred{\mysymb}{\mathclap{\myover}}_\mysub B$ : not enough space between $A$ and $\oversetred{\mysymb}{\myover}_\mysub$; the $\myover$ nearly goes over $A$\\\\
$A\oversetred{\mysymb_\mysub}{\myover} B$ : the $\myover$ is not centered properly\\\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to create the following macro `\mystack`:

```
\def\mystack#1\over#2_#3{%
   \mathrel {%
      \setbox0=\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle #1$}%
      \setbox1=\hbox{$#2$}%
      \ifdim\wd1>\wd0 \kern .5\wd1 \else \kern .5\wd0 \fi
      \vbox{
         \offinterlineskip
         \moveleft.5\wd0 \box0
         \kern.3ex
         \moveleft.5\wd1 \hbox{$#2_#3$}
}}}

% Usage:
$ A \mystack KPR \over \sqsubseteq_\rightsquigarrow B $
```

The macro measures the supperscript of the relation (in `\box0`) and the relation alone (in `\box1`). Then it appends correct kern before `\vbox`. The `\vbox` uses appropriate `\moveleft` of `\box0` and `\moveleft` of the relation including its subscript.